# How to populate selectbox on page load event in using jsp and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

i want to populate select box on page load but its not working

here is my html code file1

```
<button id="edit-btn" onclick="popupwindow('edituser.jsp','Add new user',500,300)">Edit user</button>
```

file2

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

          $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/MyServlet",
                        data: "action=list",
                        success: function(data){ 
                          alert("success");
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                            alert(errorThrown)
                        }
          });
   }); 
  </script>

<select name="currentusername" id="current-username" style="width:157px;">
</select>
```

MYDAO

```
  public List getAllUserNames(){       
    List<UserBean> users = new ArrayList<UserBean>();
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT username FROM users ";
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs != null) {
        while (rs.next()) {
             UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
             System.out.println(rs.getString("username"));
             userBean.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));

             users.add(userBean);
        }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No users");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return users;            
}
```

Servlet

```
 if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("list")){
         System.out.println("list");
         request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUserNames());          
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps :
1) convert returned list to json.
use well known libraries like gson,jackson,json.jar.
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide.
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes.
2)write returned string to response .
3)set content type to application/json.
4)in your success of ajex .

```
     success: function(data){ 
       var html ="";
       var JsonArray = JSON.parse(data);
       for(i=0; JsonArray .length >i; i++){
           html +="<option value='"+JsonArray[i].username+"'>"+JsonArray[i].username+"</option>";
       }
     $("#current-username").html(html);
    },
```